# How can I join two tables in LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use ASP.NET Core and EF Core.

I have two tables `FileType` and `UniversityFile`.

`UniversityFile` saves number of each file extensions in some universities. I want to join these two tables and get a list to send to a method which creates an Excel report.

This is an example of the `FileType` and `UniversityFile` tables:

```
{
        List<FileType> FileTypes= new List<FileType>()
        {
            new FileType() { Id = 1, Extention= "Zip" },
            new FileType() { Id = 2, Extention= "MP3" },
            new FileType() { Id = 3, Extention= "Ogg" },
        };

        List<UniversityFile> UniversityFiles= new List<UniversityFile>()
        {
            new UniversityFile() { UniversityId = 1, FileTypeId = 1, Count = 5 },
            new UniversityFile() { UniversityId = 1, FileTypeId = 2, Count = 10  },
            new UniversityFile() { UniversityId = 1, FileTypeId = 3, Count = 5 },
            new UniversityFile() { UniversityId = 2, FileTypeId = 1, Count = 10 },
            new UniversityFile() { UniversityId = 2, FileTypeId = 2, Count = 10 },
            new UniversityFile() { UniversityId = 2, FileTypeId = 3, Count = 10 }
        };
}
```

and here is the list I need to send to my method

```
var data = new List<>()
    {
        new { UniversityId = 1, Zip = 5, MP3 = 10, Ogg = 5 },
        new { UniversityId = 2, Zip = 10, MP3 = 10, Ogg = 10  },
    };
```

I tried Linq `Join`  but I can't find the right way to get the list

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working for you?

Comment: As said to your previous, similar question that you deleted: I don't really see a question here. You only state a requirement and that's all. If you show what you tried and how it failed we have something to go by. Also, your effort to prepare sample data is appreciated, but in reality the data come from an EF query, which is quite different. Seeing the class model is more useful, esp. navigation properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result = context.UniversityFiles
    .GroupBy(x => x.UniversityId)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        UniversityId = x.Key,
        Zip = x.Where(y => y.FileTypeId == 1).Sum(y => y.Count),
        MP3 = x.Where(y => y.FileTypeId == 2).Sum(y => y.Count),
        Ogg = x.Where(y => y.FileTypeId == 3).Sum(y => y.Count)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new List<object>();

foreach (var universityFile in universityFiles
    .GroupBy(universityFile => universityFile.UniversityId)) 
     result.Add(new { universityFile.Key, Zip = universityFile
         .Where(universityFile => universityFile.FileTypeId == 1)
             .Sum(universityFile => universityFile.Count), MP3 = universityFile.Where(universityFile => universityFile.FileTypeId == 2)
             .Sum(universityFile => universityFile.Count), Ogg = universityFile.Where(universityFile => universityFile.FileTypeId == 3)
             .Sum(universityFile => universityFile.Count) });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from uf in UniversityFiles
                      group uf by new { uf.UniversityId } into gr
                      from x in gr
                      select new
                      {
                          UniversityId = x.UniversityId,
                          Zip = gr.Where(y => y.FileTypeId == 1).Sum(y => y.Count),
                          MP3 = gr.Where(y => y.FileTypeId == 2).Sum(y => y.Count),
                          Ogg = gr.Where(y => y.FileTypeId == 3).Sum(y => y.Count)
                      }).Distinct().ToList();
```